# problem on union of connected sets

Tags: metric-spaces

for $v \in \mathbb R^2$ and $r>0$ let $D(v,r)$ denote the closed disc with center at $v$ and radius $r$ let $v=(5,0)$ for $\alpha >0$ let $X_\alpha $ be the subset

$X_\alpha =D(-v,3)\cup D(v,3)\cup \{(x,\alpha x):x\in \mathbb R\}$

find condition on $\alpha $ for $X_\alpha $ to be connected?

I know union of connected sets is connected if they have at least one point in common.Here $D(-v,3)\cap D(v,3)=\phi$

How does $\alpha $ affect the problem's solution.Any hints

Comment: Draw a picture.

Comment: Note that the union of $\{0\}$ and $(0,1]$ is connected but the sets are disjoint.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: the last part of the union is a line (going through the origin) that could connect the two disks. Think of what is the slope needed so it will touch the disks (in fact, you could only assert that one of them is intersected, the second will follow).